# switch view if the Webview can't loading the URL?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uiwebview

I have 2 views on my screen first is the Webview and the second is a static view "errorView" with the error message "set to hidden". I am trying to load the errorView if we have an error loading website to Webview.

```
@objc private func loadURL() {
 
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwi") else {
            self.errroLoadingWebView.isHidden = false
            return
        }
        webView?.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `WKWebView.navigationDelegate`. It has a method called `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WKNavigationDelegate`.

set delegate

```
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

```
class StaticWebPageVC: WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
    func webView(_: WKWebView, didFinish _: WKNavigation!) {
        // Web view loaded
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        // Show error view
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        // Show error view
    }
}
```